# laptop freezing and rebooting unexpectedly

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, audio, freeze

I'm using hp pavilion g 7 notebook PC.product number: (D 0 M 2 5 U A#BA)
it freezes when am playing anything with sound like movie or music.sometimes it freezes when there's no sound playing too.i displays noisy screen effect on freeze.it sometimes reboots unexpectedly.I'm using windows 8(64) bit..How do i solve this problem please?

Answer (score 0):

1) Enter the BIOS (F2) and run the hard disk test.
2) Remove the battery and look in the compartment where the battery was installed.

Answer (score 0):

Check the fan is working and that the laptop is not getting too hot. Heat is very often the cause of sporadic shutdowns.

For example, if it is getting hot underneath then try raising it up to allow some airflow - let it cool down this way and see if the airflow helps.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have `Video Card` problem. Check the driver for your Video Card if possible update it. You can check problem occurred in your system by going to

`Control Panel (Select View by Large Icons) > Performance Information and Tools > Advanced Tools > Performance Issue`s

[You can check here for HP Drivers.](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/softwareCategory?cc=us&dlc=en&lc=en&product=5128928&)